# Resolving a promise in a 'then' statement

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

With AngularJS, I resolve my promises directly in the service just like this:

```
.factory('movieService', function($http, $log, $q) {
  return {
   getMovie: function(movie) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     $http.get('/api/v1/movies/' + movie)
       .success(function(data) { 
          deferred.resolve({
             title: data.title,
             cost: data.price});
       }).error(function(msg, code) {
          deferred.reject(msg);
          $log.error(msg, code);
       });
     return deferred.promise;
   }
  }
 });
```

As stated in the documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#) :

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

So `success` and `error` got deprecated.

How can I resolve a promise in a `then` statement ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be rewritten as:

```
.factory('movieService', function($http, $log, $q) {
    return {
        getMovie: function(movie) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get('/api/v1/movies/' + movie).then(function(response){
              var data = response.data;

              deferred.resolve({
                  title: data.title,
                  cost: data.price
              });
            }, function(msg, code) {
                deferred.reject(msg);
                $log.error(msg, code);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

Although you're doing a bit more work than necessary. It can be shortened down to:

```
.factory('movieService', function($http, $log, $q) {
    return {
        getMovie: function(movie) {
            return $http.get('/api/v1/movies/' + movie).then(function(response){
              var data = response.data;

              return {
                  title: data.title,
                  cost: data.price
              };
            }, function(msg, code) {
                $log.error(msg, code);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass two functions to `then()` as parameters, the first being for success, and the second being for failure.

```
...

$http.get('/api/v1/movies/' + movie)
.then(function(result) { 
          //Your success code here
       },
      function(result) {
          //Your fail code here
       });
...
```

Strictly speaking, though, `then()` returns a promise. What you're doing is waiting for it to resolve, then using that resolve to resolve *another* promise with the same data. You don't need to bother; just return the `$http` chain. Admittedly, they could be a little clearer about `then()` in the documentation for [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: Can you please share some code about resolving a promise in a 'then' block ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
.factory('movieService', function ($http, $log, $q)
{
    return {
        getMovie: function (movie)
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
          
            $http.get('/api/v1/movies/' + movie).then(
              
                //Success as first parameter
                function (data)
                { 
                    deferred.resolve({
                        title: data.title,
                        cost: data.price
                    });
                },
              
                // Error as second parameter
                function (msg, code)
                {
                    deferred.reject(msg);
                    $log.error(msg, code);
                }
            );
          
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
 });
```